# What does “shall be a pointer to the initial element of an array of character type” mean in C99 7.19 / C11 7.21?

Tags: c, pointers, printf, language-lawyer, c11

The recent C standards specify that for `printf("%s",p)`:

> If no **l** length modiﬁer is present, the argument shall be a pointer to the initial element of an array of character type

Does that mean that `p` must be compatible with `char *`, or should this sentence be interpreted in a more lenient fashion? Do other parts of the standard clarify what exactly is meant here by “an array of character type”?

**Why this matters**: If the phrase is interpreted strictly as meaning that `p` must be compatible with `char *`, an important consequence is that `unsigned char *p; … printf("%s", p);` is undefined on a compilation platform where `char` is signed, and `const char *p; … printf("%s", p);` is undefined.

Comment: IMHO "array of character type" could mean ["const", "volatile", ""]["unsigned", "signed", ""] `char`.

Comment: I don't see how const-ness matters, only the `%n` modifier is described as writing to one of the parameters.

Comment: @Mat const-ness may matter in that `const char *` is not a type compatible with `char *`. It does not matter than `printf()` does not write there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The three types `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` are collectively called the *character types*. ...
>   C11 6.2.5 15

So an array of "character type" would encompass these 3.

`const`, `volatile`, and `restrict` are qualifiers to various types and belong to the same type category.  They apply too.

> Any type so far mentioned is an *unqualified type*. Each unqualified type has several *qualified versions* of its type, corresponding to the combinations of one, two, or all three of the `const`, `volatile`, and `restrict` qualifiers. The qualified or unqualified versions of a type are distinct types that **belong to the same type category** and have the same representation and alignment requirements. A derived type is not qualified by the qualifiers (if any) of the type from which it is derived.
>   C11 6.2.5 26

Answer (score 3):

Yes, p must be compatible with char. The main purpose of that line of text is likely to point out the distinction between char and wchar_t. It becomes clearer if you read further up in the same chapter (C11 7.21/7):

> l (ell)
>   "Specifies... that a following s conversion specifier applies
>   to a pointer to a wchar_t argument;"

If you write `%ls`, the argument must be compatible with `wchar_t[]`, otherwise to `char[]`.

As for `char` versus `unsigned char`: *formally*, a pointer to `char` is not compatible with a pointer to `unsigned char`. Passing an `unsigned char*` to `printf("%s",p)` is therefore formally undefined behavior.

However... in the real world outside the C standard, there exists no case where `unsigned char` cannot be used instead of `char` for the purpose of storing a character symbol. Simply because there exist no symbol tables with negative indices. ASCII, UTF8 and so on all start at 0 and count upwards from there. Your code will be 100% portable even though this is undefined behavior in theory

Comment: Note that “compatible with `char *`” was my attempt at formalizing what the standard says. It only says “pointer to the initial element of an array of character type” and that would appear to allow a pointer to `unsigned char` (according to the definition chux dug up) although that is not compatible with `char *`.